# Will taking a job at the UN improve my chances of getting a UK visitor visa?

Tags: visas, uk, customs-and-immigration, passports, serial-refusals

Does working for an international organization (like a UN agency) enhance the chance of getting a UK visit visa ? I have been refused twice before and would like to increase my credibility for the third application.

Comment: Are you asking whether you should try to find a job with an international organization, just so you can have a better hope of going on vacation to Britain? I mean, it's not a bad holiday destination, but I wouldn't say it is _so_ unique and nowhere-else-on-earth an experience that it ought to influence your life-and-career choice to that extent.

Comment: I have been offered a job at two places , one of them is a UN agency. I'm just wondering if that will enhance my future visa application. I would like to visit UK to sit a medical exam ( done in UK only )

Comment: Well, if you're speaking about an exam whose only purpose seems to be to qualify the taker to _practice medicine in the UK_, it will probably be extremely hard to convince an ECO that you have no intentions of emigrating to the UK ... no matter whom you work for.

Comment: Yes , I'm talking about PLAB. I thought that by working with UN I will have more ties with my country since I need to be committed to UN job contract rules.

Comment: If you are travelling on a United Nations laissez-passer you can enter the UK without a visa (or passport) at all.

Comment: Can one travel on a UN laissez-passer for personal reasons?

Comment: @ZachLipton. No, except when accompanying a family member who is a UN staffer.

Comment: @Calchas I think you meant to say "who is a UN staffer traveling for official reasons."

Comment: @ZachLipton in some countries, yes. South Africa is such a country. The UK, probably not. The US discourages the use of the LP even for official travel.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have serial refusals for your UK visa applications, but you are desperate to get in to the UK anyway and your premise is to sit the PLAB examination. You are asking if taking a job at the UN will improve your credibility for your next UK application.

> Does working for an international organization ( like a UN agency )
>   enhance the chance of getting a UK visit visa?

The answer is 'yes', having a job of any sort is an improvement in your personal circumstances, more so if your job has professional standing on an established career path.

The follow on to your question is:

> will this change in circumstances carry the application?

Probably not unless you have been doing for a long time. They tend to worry when a person's history shows a fixation on getting in to the UK. This concern is exacerbated by the fact that the PLAB exam  (Part 1) is available in countries that you can get to much easier than the UK.

I have looked at your previous questions here in our archives and the answers you got remain valid; you can still use them as a basis for developing a visa strategy.

---

Notes...

And of course if you are issued a UN passport, then the problem is solved because the UK honours diplomatic credentials from the UN, World Bank, IMF and so on.

Comment: Would completing Part 1 of PLAB somewhere else demonstrate a real intent to take PLAB, supporting an application for a visa to do so?

Comment: Would the UK honor a UN LP as a "diplomatic credential" if the bearer were traveling for personal reasons?

Comment: I would like to sit the second part of PLAB. I already passed PLAB 1.

Comment: @phoog yes they would honour the credentials. It's actually none of anybody's business why a UN diplomat is travelling (all other things being equal)

Comment: @GayotFow at https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/what-are-acceptable-travel-documents-for-entry-clearance-ecb08/ecb08-what-are-acceptable-travel-documents-for-entry-clearance#ecb815-travel-documents-issued-by-the-united-nations, they specify "on official business."

Comment: @phoog I wouldn't trust that particular material. I know it's out there and seems official but doesn't even begin to compare with macdonald's.